# What is controlling network settings?

Tags: networking

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 server on a VM, and then installing a couple of services, I have not a clue as to how to configure my network to be either static or DHCP.

There are so many posts, blogs, articles etc on how to configure network settings that I’ve not a clue as to what is “in control” of my network now.  People suggest various tools, such as nmcli (which isn’t installed by default).  Write changes to the head file, no the tail file.  It’s quite frustrating.  Use network manager, use systemmd, it’s all just a jumbled mess of different versions of Ubuntu over 15 years.  Trying to figure this out is like jumping into a Wikipedia rabbit hole.  There is just no end in site.

So are there “tells” as to what “system” is controlling my network settings?

ETA:  I’m trying to make sure I’m using static ip instead of dhcp.

Comment: What, if anything, do you want to change in your network settings? As stated your question seems like "tell me everything you know about network settings". If so it's too broad of a question.

Comment: Fair nuff.  Updated.